# Prove that $ \exists [c,d] \subset [a,b], m > 0$ such that $f(x) \geq m$ for $x \in [c,d]$.

Tags: calculus, integration

if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and  $\int _{a}^{b} f(x)dx >0$. Prove that $ \exists [c,d] \subset [a,b], m > 0$ such that $f(x) \geq m$ for $x \in [c,d].$

Could anyone give me a hint for proving this?

Comment: Darboux lower sum.

Comment: This is not a measure course @BrevanEllefsen just advanced calculus one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prove by contradiction. If this is not true then the minimum in each interval of any partition is $\leq 0$ so each lower Riemann sum is $\leq 0$ which makes the integral $\leq 0$.

Comment: If the claim is not true, does it mean $\forall [c,d] \subseteq [a,b], \forall m > 0, \exists x_0 \in [c, d]\colon f(x_0) < m$? Then how could we assert that the infimum of each subinterval $\leqslant 0$ [I don't think this is obvious]?

Comment: @xbh Just take $m=\frac 1 n$ and get a points $x_n$ where $f(x_n) <\frac 1 n$. Doesn't that make the infimum $\leq 0$.

Comment: Thanks for explanation!